# Error Page For Ajax Enabled Page asp.net

Tags: ajax

i have a page with update panel. if any error occurs then page does not display any information regarding error. How to display error page.

Thank you
Mohan Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/29/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Handling-Errors-with-the-UpdatePanel-control-using-ASP.NET-AJAX.aspx) by scottgu on how to do this.

> *1) You can now handle the
>    "OnAsyncPostBackError" event on the
>     control to catch
>    and/or modify an error message that
>    occurs during the processing of an
>    AJAX postback callback on the server.*
>
> *2) You can now set the
>    "AllowCustomErrors" property on the
>     control to enable
>    the standard ASP.NET custom error
>    support to be enabled to redirect a
>    user automatically to an error page
>    when an error occurs (even if it is
>    happening during an AJAX postback).*
>
> *3) You can now optionally handle
>    client-side JavaScript events on the
>    page to intercept any error message
>    sent back from the server, and perform
>    custom client-side actions as a result
>    (for example: to output the error
>    message to a nicely formatted 
>    section instead of performing a pop-up
>    message).*